# Grade change notification in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

Here is my Excel sheet. Every day I will get entries of new grades for all the student. So the number of rows will increase everyday.It is possible that a new student might get added/be absent for the exam. I want to create a column which compares grades with previous grades available and then prints up/down based on increase/decrease. If it is same as that of previous nothing is blank. Here is example.

[image]

Now I want to know>>

1. Is this possible using advanced Excel formula? Can anyone suggest how?
2. I can't use macros as my file has to be .xlsx

Thank you

Comment: A comment to bullet no 2: Just because your result must be xlsx, there's no reason not to use macros. They can be placed in add-ons or other (macro enabled) workbooks.

Comment: This change, does it refer to the last score for that student above the one being referenced or the very first?

Comment: @ScottCraner:  Last score of the same student. Like john's score will be compared with john's last available score only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($C$1:INDEX(C:C,ROW()-1))/($C$1:INDEX(C:C,ROW()-1)=C2),1)) < B2,"Up",IF(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($C$1:INDEX(C:C,ROW()-1))/($C$1:INDEX(C:C,ROW()-1)=C2),1)) > B2,"Down","")),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi it worked! Like magic! I am a beginner to formulas in Excel. Can you please tell me how do I improve my expertise in Excel formulas?

Comment: Practice, practice and more practice.  When you have a need do research.  Or just browse by the Excel-Formula tag here.